# Access shared memory from another class

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am writing some data to the shared memory in Firebase listener class.
I could see that the data is written and I am able to read the same data in the same class.
But I want to read the data written to the shared memory from my Firebasemessaging service class.

When I try reading the shared memory data from my messaging service class, it doesn't have any data that was written in OnChildAdded method.
Any Help is appreciated.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

SharedPreferences settings1 = this.getSharedPreferences("UserInfo",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    List<String> sampleReturnList = SharePrefUtil.pullStringList(settings1, sampleName);

    for(String listItem : sampleReturnList){
        Log.d("Item Messaging", listItem);
    }
}
}
public class FirebaseEventListener implements ChildEventListener {

private DataListAdapter userList;
private Context mContext;
public static SharedPreferences settings ;
public static String sampleName = "sample";
private String NotificationMessage;

public FirebaseEventListener(DataListAdapter userList, Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    this.userList = userList;
}

public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) 
{
SharedPreferences settings = 
mContext.getSharedPreferences("UserInfo",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        List<String> sampleList = new ArrayList();
     Log.d("Item Status", (String) dataSnapshot.child("7").getValue());
        if (( dataSnapshot.child("7").getValue()).equals("In Progress") )
     {

         String NotificationMessage= (String) dataSnapshot.child("0").getValue()+"-->"+(String) dataSnapshot.child("1").getValue();
            sampleList.add(NotificationMessage);

        }
SharePrefUtil.pushStringList(settings, sampleList, sampleName);

}
}

public class SharePrefUtil {


    public static void pushStringList(SharedPreferences sharedPref, List<String> list, String uniqueListName) {

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putInt(uniqueListName + "_size", list.size());

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            editor.remove(uniqueListName + i);
            editor.putString(uniqueListName + i, list.get(i));
        }
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static List<String> pullStringList(SharedPreferences sharedPref,
                                              String uniqueListName) {

        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        int size = sharedPref.getInt(uniqueListName + "_size", 0);

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            result.add(sharedPref.getString(uniqueListName + i, null));
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: 1) show me your SharePrefUtil class.2 ) i don't see you reading from prefs

Comment: I have added the code Anton

Comment: I don't see pushStringList in your code.

Comment: I have added. I missed adding in the initial message.

Comment: I mean you don't call it in your code

Comment: Added pushStringList. I also called the pullStringList to verify whether the data is written to the shared memory in the Firebaseeventlistener class and it works fine. But when I call the pullStringList in the FirebaseMessaging Service its not working as expected.